# String to float vs double conversion

Tags: c#, numbers

Why is fvalue1 123456792 after the following line of code has executed?

```
float fvalue1 = Convert.ToSingle("123456789", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Converting to double works as expected:

```
double dvalue1 = Convert.ToDouble("123456789", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: also note `double d = 123456789;
            float f = (float) d; // f is 123456792`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've just discovered for yourself the reason double type exists - its precision is better then float's.

Check out following on the differences between these types: [Difference between decimal, float and double in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/what-is-the-difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

float doesn't have the required precision to represent 123456789, whereas double does.

Comment: [Are you sure?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.maxvalue.aspx)

Comment: @Uwe I am. Still need to learn to not couch my language with unnecessary qualifiers :)

Comment: @dlev Can you explain, why the precision is relevant here, since the number contains no decimal places, but just an integer?

Comment: @Uwe: **The number certainly does contain decimal places.** Remember how a float is stored. A float is a binary number 1.0101010101010 multiplied by 2^x for some integer x. A float is a sign bit, an integer representing the exponent, and the digits after the "1."

Comment: Thanks, @Eric - I really never got into the storage of floating points and all that epsilon stuff. Have do to some homework, I guess.

Comment: @Uwe: See my series on floating point arithmetic if you want the basics and some fun facts about Benford's Law. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/floating+point+arithmetic/